# Controls overlapping tabitem wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabitem

I have a `TabControl`,inside one `Tabitem`, i have a grid and my userControl inside the grid:

```
     <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="288,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354">
        <Canvas>
        <local:MyCustomComboBox x:Name="ucc1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" ClipToBounds="True"/>
     <Canvas>
    </Grid>
  <TabItem>
 <TabControl>
```

By default,when the userControl's size is greater than the grid's/TabItem's size,the extra portion can't be seen.How can i make my UserControl overlap it ? I tried to add `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` but it didn't work :(

Comment: You want your user control to be larger than the tab where it is hosted?

Comment: *"when the userControl's size is greater than the grid's/TabItem's size,the extra portion can't be seen"* That's to be expected. Can you add a screenshot/sketch of what you **want** it to look like? As it is now your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabItem` has it's own bounds which u cannot overlap.So,there's no way u can achieve your goal ... But i always try my best to help people, so here's a quick tip :

> If the usercontrol is bigger than the gird

Your userControl XAML includes `MyCustomComboBox`, which makes me think it is a combobox..I've seen your previous post where you wanted to customize your combobox but couldn't quite achieve your goals...So, are you trying to create you own custom combobox and by `usercontrol bigger than the grid` , did u mean that the drop down menu u created doesn't go outside the grid rather is clipped to the grid ??

If this is the case , u can use a `ContextMenu` and move your custom drop-down list there.Then the `contextMenu` will overlap both the TabItem and Grid as it is a window itself.

Also , **NOTE** that u cannot use Named content in usercontrol(u can but that requires a workaround).So i suggest you to add all required code behinds , even set required binding from the user-control's code behind.

Hope this helps :)